# How to use MySQL indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I tried to create an index on MySQL using this query

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, age INT, INDEX(id,age));
```

`DESCRIBE test;` gives this:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| age   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When i tried to found why just the id was indexed i found 2 more things. That CREATE INDEX query requeires a name for the index and also that there is a `USE INDEX ()` statement.

Now my questions:

1. Is the first query wrong or did I indexed both the id and the age like a pair and that's why just ID shows to be indexed?
2. Can I create indexes without providing a name, as I did in the first query (or when setting a column PRIMARY KEY)?
3. Should I add `USE INDEX` everytime I want to use the index? If yes, are there situations when the index is used by default (for example, when creating an index without a name, if possible)?

Comment: `MUL` means "multipart". Your query is fine. No, you don't need to `use index`. I don't understand what your problem is. Try reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create table query with index - is ok, you can check it by running command 

`SHOW INDEX FROM test` you'll see your index.

In general, it's good practice to create an index with own name (even you can omit it like in your query).

And `USE INDEX` - it's query performance optimization keyword which is just a suggestion which key mysql can use (you mush use it only if you clearly understand what are you doing, you must not use it for everyone query).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE` !

The `DESCRIBE` that you presented disagrees with the existence of `INDEX(id,age)`.

Normally, `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of a table.  You have broken with tradition; please explain what your intent is.

Do not use `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX` -- it may help 'today', but is likely to hurt 'tomorrow'.  Let the Optimizer decide which (*if any*) index to use.

We can't critique a schema without knowing what `SELECTs` you will be using against it.

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Note:  A PK is, by definition (in MySQL) both `UNIQUE` and `INDEX`.

There is almost no use for the name of an index.  If you don't name an index, a name will be generated.  A name is necessary when `DROPping` the index.